# Get response data from Angular Factory using $resource

Tags: angularjs, factory, angular-resource, ngresource, angularjs-factory

I try to get response data from angular service created by factory and $resource. I want to send POST request to server to create object in db and received created ID.

So I create service like this:

```
angular.module('sample')
    .factory('Client', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('api/clients/:id', {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I use Client service in controller:

```
 $scope.create = function () {
            Client.save($scope.client,
                function (response) {
                    $state.go("clientDetail", {'id' : whereIsMyId.id? })
                });

        };
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to read data in response.
As response I just get number like "6" but this could be any JSON.

Thank you.

Comment: could you try `$state.go("clientDetail", {'id' : response.id })` if response is the only property return by the service

Comment: Thank you this work but I need to return data in format like { "id" : 16 }. Previously I return only plain numer like "16". Plain numer for me is better so if anybody have idea how handle plain format please help.

Comment: then you should use `$state.go("clientDetail", {'id' : parseInt(response.id) })`